# jquery selector context vs chain when used from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, selector

I think I've found a solution to a problem I've been facing for the last couple days, but I don't for the life of me understand why.

I have an `<input>` field in a parent window, and then an `<iframe>` that manipulates it.  The input field has a listener for `change` events, but since it's a `hidden` input, I have to manually fire the `.change()` event to invoke the listener.  The iframe script is like so (*the `.change()` trigger is actually chained to the first line, but for illustration of my problem I've broken this into two lines*)...

```
$('#input_field',window.parent.document).val('somevalue');
$('#input_field',window.parent.document).change();
```

The first line successfully updates the value of the `<input>` field. The second line **does not** fire the `change` event and so my listener is never invoked.  This makes no sense at all.  I finally changed the way I called the parent windows change on the input field to the following...

```
parent.$('#input_field').change();
```

Now the listener is successfully invoked.

My question is **why does the first example using selector context NOT work, while the second method, chaining from `parent`, DOES work?**

---

**EDIT:** I should add, this is jQuery v1.11.3